# Name for when the addition of two elements of a set also belongs to the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Considering the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$,

$$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a + b \in \mathbb{Z}$$

This is not true for all sets. If $$A = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$$
then $$2 + 3 = 5 \notin A$$

So is there a name for the property that the sum of two elements in a set is also contained in the set?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We say that the set $A$ is closed under addition, more formally that means we have a binary operation $+ :A\times A \to A$.

We can extend this concept to any binary operation, not just addition. We can talk about a set being closed under multiplication, like $\mathbb{R}^{\ast}$ or the set of symmetries of a polygon being closed under composition. In such a case we say that the set $A$ satisfies a *closure property*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this a topic of set theory, or something else like group theory?

Comment: @Vermillion both - closure as a property on its own is something that can be studied within the confines of set theory. However one of the basic axioms of a group $(G, \circ)$ is that the underlying set must be closed under the binary operation $\circ$ - so closure is something that we take for granted in group theory rather than study it in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Additionally, we sometimes refer to "the closure of S under operation x", which means "the smallest possible set that contains S such that it is closed under x". So the closure of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ under addition winds up being the positive integers, while the closure of $\{2, 4, 6\}$ under addition would be the positive even numbers.